# Using jQuery Hover and Link on HTML Object

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, svg

I have an object which holds an .svg image. What I'm looking to do is use jQuery to change the default greyed image (dribble.svg) to a full colour image (dribble_over.svg) on hover.

I have implemented this code which doesn't appear to work.

HTML:

```
<div class="socialMediaContainer">
     <object type="image/svg+xml" data="images/social/dribbble.svg" width="74px" height="60px" id="dribble"></object>
     <a href="" target="_blank">Dribble</a>
</div>
```

jQuery:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("#dribble").hover(function() {
        $("this").attr("data", "images/social/dribbble_over.svg");
    });

});
```

My 2 questions are:

1. How can adjust my jQuery to accomodate the hover effect in changing the .svg image which i presume can be done by changing the attribute of the object image?
2. How do i tie in a link with the object?

Originally i was using an img tag to hold the .svg image however upon research and browser stability it seemed that using object was the more sensible choice. However I'm not faced with these issues that I just can't seem to overcome.

Thanks in advance for your response.

Simon

Comment: `$("this")` != `$(this)` ...

Comment: images/social/dri `bbb` le.svg is that on purpose or a typo?

Comment: You can't put an `<a>` round an `<object>` and make it a link, you'd have to use `<image>` or put a transparent `<div>` over the `<object>` and link the `<div>`. If the images are the same except for one's greyscale, I'd have implemented this in SVG by having one SVG file with an feColorMatrix filter to grey it out removing the filter on hover, all within the SVG file itself, no javascript required.

Comment: Floris I read your comment and thought I'd made an error though it seems I have actually named my image 'dribbble'! I'll wait till I've found a solution before changing names but thanks for the heads up!

@reyaner - Thanks for your code though I'm not sure how to implement to try. can you assist?

RobertLongson - Thanks for your input, will check it out!

Answer (score 0):

there is no hover , aka mouseover/mouseout on object...
maybe this might work:

```
$(".socialMediaContainer").hover(function(){
    $("#dribble").attr("data", "images/social/dribbble_over.svg");
}, function(){
    $("#dribble").attr("data", "images/social/dribbble.svg"); 
});
```

Comment: Unfortunately the codes not working on either browser. It's frustrating as it seems such a simple piece of code to implement though it just doesn't want to know! argghhhhhhh!!